# How do I list the network drives available to me in VBA (as a consequence of using Sharepoint)?

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-word

Our company recently installed SharePoint which sometimes has adverse effects when running Word VBA add-ins.  We are currently using Office 2013, though Excel seems to be largely unaffected.

One thing which works for us is to map the SharePoint area to a "legacy" drive letter using `net use`,

```
net use z: https://sharepoint.con/departmentalStuff/etc/...
```

As it persists over multiple user logins and is in effect until canceled or changed, `net use` is not too hard on the users.

Naturally, addin users would indirectly use the various VBA-supplied canned dialogue boxes such as `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` to navigate among their various directories, both Sharepoint and non-Sharepoint, and select files.  These dialogue boxes display files with the legacy drive letters assigned by `net use`.  So far so good.

However, the canned VBA dialogue boxes picking from a Sharepoint source will not return the legacy file names but rather UNC file names which are incompatible with the code further downstream.  My hackish workaround is to simply convert the file names using the following function (adapted from code found on SO):

```
Public Function toLegacyName(uncName As String) As String

    uncName = Replace(uncName, "https://", "//")
    uncName = Replace(uncName, "/", "\")
    If Left(uncName, 2) <> "\\" Then
        toLegacyName = uncName
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim network As Object: Set network = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Dim netDrives As Object: Set netDrives = network.EnumNetworkDrives
    Dim drives As String: drives = "Network drive Mappings:" & Chr(13)
    Dim myLet As String
    Dim myUnc As String

    Dim i As Long

    ' loop through all network drives
    For i = 0 To netDrives.Count - 1 Step 2
        drives = drives & "Drive " & netDrives(i) & " = " & netDrives(i + 1) & Chr(13)
        myLet = netDrives.Item(i)
        myUnc = netDrives.Item(i + 1)
        myUnc = Replace(myUnc, "@SSL", "") ' installation-dependent ?

        ' hopefully we find it here
        If InStr(LCase(uncName), LCase(myUnc)) Then
            toLegacyName = myLet & Right(uncName, Len(uncName) - Len(myUnc))
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    ' drive not mapped or something
    MsgBox drives, vbOKOnly, "Error with UNC file name " & uncName
    toLegacyName = ""

End Function
```

While this code works for me, I see that the list of drive letters in netDrives is not necessarily complete.  Some drive letters assigned by `net use` may be missing, possibly when the network resource is reused, as in

```
net use x: https://sharepoint.con/departmentalStuff/Marketing/... 
net use y: https://sharepoint.con/departmentalStuff/Research/...
```

Is there a better way to determine all the drive mappings apart from `WScript.Network`?  Are solutions specific to Sharepoint when using Word addins?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54853243/11509084