# VBScript add network place

Tags: networking, vbscript, shortcut

I want to create a network place using VBScript. These are stored in: C:\Users\Danespe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts

When I use the following code, I get a shortcut in that folder, with an arrow icon, and the shortcut appears in the folder.

```
    Set sys_sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set sys_ap = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    strNetHood = sys_ap.Namespace(&H13&).Self.Path
    strShortcutName = "PaleoNAS"
    strShortcutPath = "\\Paleo-NAS\PM2"
    Set objShortcut = sys_sh.CreateShortcut(strNetHood & "\" & strShortcutName & ".lnk")
    objShortcut.TargetPath = strShortcutPath
    objShortcut.Save
```

When I manually add a network place, I get a file (not a shortcut) in that same folder, but also with an arrow icon, AND the file appears in the left-hand pane of Windows Explorer, at the bottom of the My Computer block.

I would like to achieve the second result, of the file also appearing in the Explorer pane, but via VBScript, instead of manually.

Comment: Adds a shared network drive to your computer system.

`wsh.MapNetworkDrive(strLocalName, strRemoteName, [bUpdateProfile], [strUser], [strPassword])`?

Comment: Sorry, not getting any results with that. Tried all sorts of variations and all I get is various error messages. Can you expand that answer a bit?

BTW, I do NOT want to create a mapped network DRIVE, with a letter and colon to access it. I looked up the command and that seems to me is where it is aimed. If that's what this is supposed to do, then thank you, but that's not what I'm after.

Comment: Well if you map a drive it will magically appears where you want it. A link in the following folder `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\c$ (127.0.0.1)`

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I want to use a network PLACE, not a network DRIVE.

Comment: Similar to your answer, may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30914452/2861476) could help

Comment: Yes, thank you, that also has usable elements.

Answer (score 0):

I found something in another forum that works. This does the trick. I don't understand the internals of the target.lnk file, but this does what I need.

```
Dim fs,Shell,DomainADSPath
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fs = Createobject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")

CreateNetworkLink "NewNetLink","\\Paleo-NAS\PM2","My Home directory"

Sub CreateNetworkLink(LinkName,LinkTargetPath,LinkDescription)
'> Get the path to the Network Neighborhood special folder.
Set NetHoodfolder = fs.getfolder(Shell.SpecialFolders("NetHood"))
Folder=NetHoodFolder &"\" &LinkName
If Fs.FolderExists(Folder)=False Then 
   Fs.CreateFolder(Folder)
   set LinkFolder=fs.getfolder(Folder)
   Linkfolder.attributes=1
End If
   CreateLink Folder,"target.lnk",LinkTargetPath,LinkDescription,"",""
   WriteFile Folder &"\Desktop.ini","[.ShellClassInfo]",2
   WriteFile Folder &"\Desktop.ini","CLSID2={0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}",8
   WriteFile Folder &"\Desktop.ini","Flags=2",8
   WriteFile Folder &"\Desktop.ini","ConfirmFileOp=0",8
End Sub

'>This Subroutine Creates the Shortcut Based on the parameters sent to it.
Sub CreateLink(LinkLocation,LinkName,LinkTargetPath,LinkDescription,LinkWorkingDirectory,LinkIconLocation)
    Set ShellLink = Shell.CreateShortcut(LinkLocation &"\" & LinkName)
    ShellLink.TargetPath = LinkTargetPath
    ShellLink.WindowStyle = 1
    ShellLink.Description = LinkDescription
    ShellLink.WorkingDirectory = LinkWorkingDirectory
    'shelllink.IconLocation = LinkIconLocation
    ShellLink.Save
End Sub

'> This function writes to a file
Function WriteFile(Filename,Text,AccessType)
   'Const ForWriting = 2, ForAppending=8 
   Dim fs, f
   Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(FileName, AccessType, true)
   f.WriteLine Text
   f.Close
End Function
```